# MySQL Php Syntax Error, Check the manual

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been having trouble with my code, and I keep getting this error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]" at line 1

My code for this is as follows:

```
 <?
//indicate the database you want
$db_name="test";

//connect to database
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
//start the sql statement
$sql = @"CREATE TABLE $_POST[table_name] (";


for ($i =0;$i < count($_POST['field_name']);$i++){
    $sql .=$_POST['field_name'][$i]." ".$_POST['field_type'][$i];
    if ($_POST["field_length"][$i] !="") {
        $sql .= " (".$_POST ["field_length"][$i]."),";
    } else {
        $sql .= ",";
    }
}
//clean up
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
$sql .= ")";
//execute
$result = mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

//get a good message for success
if ($result) {
    $msg = "<P>".$_POST['table_name']." has been created!</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

I have a form seperate for table name, and number of fields, a seperate php doc for the other database stuff, it is just giving me trouble on my local host whenever I try to run this document after the other two.

After Echoing edited statements for $sql and $_POST I received the message,

"CREATE TABLE $_POST[table_name]"...$_POST[table_name]"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]"...hey char (1))' at line 1"

Comment: Sanitize your inputs. Never relay unchecked user input.

Comment: can we get an echo $sql please?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$_POST[table_name]` is not replaced with the value in your query try

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ". $_POST['table_name']." (";
```

Comment: No luck, I got the error
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]" (hey char (1))' at line 1"

Everything else except table name showed up again

Comment: "CREATE TABLE $_POST[table_name]" (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]" (free char (1))' at line 1"

Is what I received after I echo'd on line 10, after line 9

Comment: very strange did you use the exact code i provided because where are the single quotes in $_POST[table_name]

Comment: " CREATE TABLE $_POST[table_name]" (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]" (hey char (1))' at line 1"

Is what I received after recopy and pasting it, since i'm trying multiple answers at a time. No luck availed after double checking, and the echo appears to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put table_name in ', because you want to access the $_POST['table_name'].

That's why your query must begin like this:

> "CREATE TABLE ".$_POST['table_name']."..

And you should always escape $_POST[] or $_GET[] values to prevent SQL Injection.

Use the function [mysql_real_escape_string($_POST...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for escaping or use [prepared statements with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also mysql_... is deprecated. Switch to [mysqli_..](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)!

Comment: I'm still receiving the error,
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]" (hey char (1))' at line 1"

Comment: That can't be, because table_name is not longer in the $sql String. Are you sure you wrote EXACTLY $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$_POST['table_name']."..."; ?

Comment: Yes, I just copy and pasted that exact statement, and i'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Can you just echo me your $sql please? AND your $_POST['table_name'] echo also?

Comment: Yep,
I receive this:
CREATE TABLE $_POST[table_name]"...$_POST[table_name]"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[table_name]"...hey char (1))' at line 1

Comment: That can't be...except $_POST['table_name'] contains $_POST[table_name]. Are you sure you updated this in the file on your webserver and not only in a local file?

Comment: I did not update any file on my webserver, just through local files.

Comment: That cannot work...PHP files are executed on the webserver. You have to upload the file to your webserver for example through ftp or copy it to the local directory, where your webserver is installed, if you for example use XAMPP.

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to mysql and php, i'm taking it as one of my classes.
I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: Then you have to copy your file to your htdocs folder for example.

Comment: It is located in a subfolder in htdocs
\htdocs\CMPT210\lab 8\createtable2.php

Comment: localhost/cmpt210/lab%208/createtable2.php

Is how it appears

Comment: Yeah that looks right. And you are sure you edit the file in htdocs\cmpt20\lab 8\ and not on your Desktop or somewhere else?

Comment: Yep, I'm thinking that it isn't accessing my table_name in my previous documents, which I don't understand since the document before it was able to access it just fine.

Comment: That your echo is exactly the same as before I think that there is a saving problem. If the document can access $_POST['table_name'] then the echo should be an error or at least "CREATE TABLE  ....", because $_POST['table_name'] is emtpy.